# Get values from looped input fields and post to DB. Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i have a form in my view which has input fields looped to get same values  for a given time period [ex: 7 days]. Depends on fdate to ldate. I am getting the fields for the given time period, the Problem is, how do i get the values for each input fields and post them to the database table 'work_week'. I am stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the Code snippet.

```
<?php for(;strtotime($fdate)<=strtotime($ldate);){ ?>

   <label>Date</label>
   <input class="form-control" name="fdate" value='<?php echo $fdate; ?>' readonly>

   <label>Place Visited</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="outletVisited" placeholder="Name of outlet visited">

 <?php
  $fdate=date("d-m-Y",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($fdate)));
 }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple pass it as a **array**. Build array with dynamic date as a key for each input like this .

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="outletVisited[<?php echo $fdate; ?>]" placeholder="Name of outlet visited"><br>
```